# Fill values in each row of pandas dataframe based on condition and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table that looks like this:

| CLI_CD | CURA_T1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

What I need to do is to add a column named 'CURA_ALT' that needs to recognize the first appearence of the number 1 in the column 'CURA_T1', and based on this first appearence, I need the column 'CURA_ALT' to be filled with the division of 100/6. But in each row, I need the division to sum up with the result from the previous cell in the same column.

Also, there are different ID (CLI_CD), so I need to groupby the column 'CLI_CD' to get the result.

What I expect is a DataFrame that looks like this:

| CLI_CD | CURA_T1 | CURA_ALT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 17 |
| 3 | 1 | 33 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 67 |
| 3 | 1 | 83 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The logic is not very clear.
The example is not appropriate.
If you need to use `groupby`, you should create an example that uses `groupby`.
Is it because the value of 1 is 6 that the value of 6 divided by 100 is assigned sequentially? This is also unclear.

Comment: @PandaKim I'm sorry I wasn't able to express the problem very clearly. The value 1 in the column 'CURA_T1' always follow a succesion of 6 appearances, that is why the value in the new column must be divided by 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df['CURA_ALT'] = df.groupby(df['CURA_T1'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount() * 100/6
df['CURA_ALT'] = df['CURA_ALT'].astype(int)
df

    CLI_CD  CURA_T1  CURA_ALT
0        3        0         0
1        3        0         0
2        3        0         0
3        3        0         0
4        3        1        16
5        3        1        33
6        3        1        50
7        3        1        66
8        3        1        83
9        3        1       100
10       3        0         0
11       3        0         0
```

Note that the outcome is a little different due to rounding

Comment: It works really well. Thank you VERY MUCH.
Someone else also posted a solution that looked like this, and it also worked:

df['CURA_ALT'] = df.groupby('CLI_CD')['CURA_T1'].cumsum().where(df['CURA_T1'].eq(1)).mul(100).div(6).fillna(0).astype('int')

This other solution also worked really well! I want to thank you guys that helped.